# No main.gls file is produced

Tags: glossaries

I want to produce a glossary and I'm pretty sure I'm following the instructions but no `main.gls` file is produced. There is something I must be missing here but what?

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\newglossaryentry{computer}
{
  name=computer,
  description={is a programmable machine that receives input,
               stores and manipulates data, and provides
               output in a useful format}
}
\newglossaryentry{naiive}
{
  name=na\"{\i}ve,
  description={is a French loanword (adjective, form of naïf)
               indicating having or showing a lack of experience,
               understanding or sophistication},
  sort=naiive
}
\newglossaryentry{Linux}
{
  name=Linux,
  description={is a generic term referring to the family of Unix-like
               computer operating systems that use the Linux kernel},
  plural=Linuces
}

%%% Glossary Test

This is just a test for glossary entries and the resulting glossary:

\Gls{naiive} people don't know about alternative \gls{computer} operating systems: \glspl{Linux}, BSDs and GNU/Hurd.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

The text itself is produced just fine:

[image]

but no glossary, and I get an error message *no file main.gls*. I have tried locally with `kile` and `gummi` on an up-to-date Debian.

Comment: Did you run `makeglossaries` or the lua version of it? It does not run by it self (though some compiling tools may run it automatically)

Comment: Thanks, @daleif, this helps as long as I compile manually. Isn't `\makeglossaries` intended to kick off the process? Also, in environments where you don't have control, such as `Overleaf`, or `gummi` which caches the interim files somewhere else, things get complicated. But I'm afraid I'll have to work it out somehow...

Comment: No, `\makeglossaries` only starts the file that collects the glossary data. On overleaf the compiler system latexmk is used. I'm quite sure it has settings that will run `makeglossaries` automatically when needed, otherwise it can easily be added. Don't know about gummi as I'm personally a long time latexmk user.

Comment: In respect of Overleaf, the interesting situation is that it works for me (sort of, I still have issues with interim files, in particular the .glsdefs, that aren't updated)  --  but the person I share the project with gets a compile error. Probably something I have to discuss with the Overleaf team!

Comment: In Overleaf, I found the "clear cache" button and all good now. It's at the end of the logs window.

Answer (score 0):

In Kile you could set LaTeXmk for real-time preview exactly the same way as pdfLaTeX. If its not there then you would need to add it to Configure Tools Build.

[image]

Also your gummi should have a LaTeXmk option for real-time preview (Certainly its included in windows 0.6 series. I don't normally use it but if I switch it on in windows then in a both cases a simple file without bib entries will real-time preview / compile as I edit since its just the single pdfTeX per second.

[image]

In kile you could also add a command chain of your own choice such as pdfLaTeX+makeindex+glossaries+pdflatex+pdflatex and only switch that on "ad-hoc" when checking, since the combined run time could interfere with normal work flow unless you set the trigger timer higher (say after 5 seconds).

[image]

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't help - in Gummi I can choose mklatex but it doesn't change the outcome, and in Kile I rather use the integrated konsole window to manually dick off `makeglossaries` - as it turns out, I need to explicitly clean out the interim `*.gls*` files to make glossary changes appear in the document. I'll probably write a short script to get this done, or finally get into using a `make` file.